# Appending x characters to string

Tags: c, string

I'd expect, that the lines below would take at most 6 chars from variable `filename` and append it to variable `dmpfilename`:

```
sprintf (dmpfilename, "InstrumentList_FULL.csv_%.*s",6,  filename);
sprintf (dmpfilename, "InstrumentList_FULL.csv_%*s" ,6,  filename);
sprintf (dmpfilename, "InstrumentList_FULL.csv_%6s",     filename);
```

But they append more characters (they take filename till '\0').
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first attempt should work, it uses the precision which has the correct semantics according to [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf):

> This gives [...] the maximum number of characters to be printed from a string for s and S conversions.

For the others, you're not doing anything wrong, except having the wrong expectations. The [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) clearly states:

> In no case does a nonexistent or small field width cause truncation of a field; if the result of a conversion is wider than the field width, the field is expanded to contain the conversion result.

You're expecting truncation but not getting it, since that's not how it works.

I tested the precision-based one (with `%.*s`) and it worked fine.

Comment: Ugh, I'm just following this casually and too busy to crack a manual but isn't there are way to truncate? I know with numbers at least, there is a `n.n` syntax, where one of the values does truncate. Doesn't that work with strings?